# How to draw circle in opengles

Tags: opengl-es

Here is my part of code to show circle on screen but unfortunate circle is not coming on screen.

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
 glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

const float DEG2RAD = 3.14159/180;

for (int i=0; i < 360; i++)
{
    float degInRad = i*DEG2RAD;
    glVertex2f(cos(degInRad)*8,sin(degInRad)*8);
}

 glEnd();
glFlush();
```

I am not understanding code is seems to look ok but circle is not coming on screen.

Comment: Hi Ajay, try this link - might help answer your question :) http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/circles-and-ellipses-in-opengl-es.html

Comment: Side note: Every call to `glPushMatrix()` should be matched by a call to `glPopMatrix()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circle is too big. The default viewport is in the range [(-1 -1), (1 1)].

BTW, you don't need 360 segments. About 30 is usually adequate, depending on how smooth you want it.

Comment: I am new to ES I edited the segment upto 30 but still not visible.

Comment: Where did you say to modify? in loop through?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised why my answer might be confusing. The segment count is just a suggestion; it should work fine with 360 segments. The problem is the radius of 8. It will be drawn entirely outside the viewport. Try a radius of 0.8 instead.

Comment: Now it is running fine... A question I just started to learn. Thanks for help.